# Timer Control in C# windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, timer

I am a beginner with windows forms (visual studio 2010) , and wanted to know is there any way to get the value of a timer at any instant of time ?
For starters i want to lets say display the value of a timer in a text box e.g if my timer is from 0 to 100, i want to show these values 0 to 100 all the way in a textbox.

Secondly, is there a timer variable which may give the number of times my timer has ticked since it was started?

Comment: It sounds like you'd be better off with the [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class. You can use it conjunction with a timer if you need to, just reset it when the timer fires.

Comment: I'm tempted to side with the above comments here, but on the event that LarsTech is wrong, we'd love to see some details of what you've tried and researched. It's way faster for us to solve your problem when we know what you've already tried, then for us to guess and you to tell us that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want a [`Stopwatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx), as mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24875356/timer-control-in-c-sharp-windows-form#comment38635917_24875356).

You can use the `Start` command whenever you start the `Timer` (if you find you even still need that), then check `Elapsed` when you want to know how long has passed, for instance in the `Timer.Tick` event.

As for your second question, you'll need a private field to track your tick count, but that's easy enough. Just increment the number on each tick and forget about it. No big deal.

Comment: yes for the first question , i am gonna be needing timers and stopwatches to work in parallel , and for second question, i figured it was basic stuff ,so there might be a built-in function for it in timers ...

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem, partly because it is so open ended.

1. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`

   - You would need to write an event handler which would be executed whenever the timer ticks. This timer must be hosted on a form.
2. `System.Threading.Timer`

   - You would need to specify a callback delegate which executes when the timer ticks. This doesn't need a form to run.
3. `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`

   - This is a class which can be started and stopped, and can tell you the amount of time elapsed since it was started.

`System.Threading.Timer` example to make a simple counter

```vb
Private t As System.Threading.Timer
Private counter As Long = 0
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    t = New System.Threading.Timer(Sub() counter += 1)
    t.Change(1000, 1000) ' 1000 (ms): start after 1 second, 1000 (ms): 1 second interval
End Sub
Public ReadOnly Property Counts As Long
    Get
        Return counter
    End Get
End Property
Public Sub ResetCounter()
    t.Change(System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite)
    counter = 0
    t.Change(1000, 1000)
End Sub
```